# installation of Ubuntu with VMware on Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I have installed VMware Workstation on my PC. Now I am getting 3 options: VMware player, VMware Workstation, VMware Network Editor.

What option I should use to install Ubuntu? I have Windows on my PC and want to use Ubuntu as an optional OS. I have also downloaded the Ubuntu Desktop Edition.

Please guide me the next steps to use Ubuntu on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

The player will do the job and is free for personal use. Workstation is the 'professional' version and is free to evaluate but is not free if you continue to use it. Follow the steps to create a new virtual machine - it's very intuitive; in fact, I did this for Ubuntu this afternoon and it took about 15 minutes - about the same time as installing Ubuntu on a 'blank' PC.

Comment: To add, you can use "pre-made" installations of Ubuntu (as well as other OS and special software) by downloading "appliances" through VMware's web site: http://www.vmware.com/appliances/